# how to use the where clause in laravel to retrieve different categories of products in the same table

Tags: laravel

I am currently making an ecommerce site and am new to Laravel, and at the moment I'd like to retrieve data based on different categories from the same table, using a where clause to store the retrieved data in separate variables. The problem here is whenever I run this code it say undefined variable $newproducts. Below is my code. Thanks in advance

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $allproducts=product::all();
        $bestsellerproducts=product::where('category','iphone 11')->get();
        $newproducts=product::where('category','iphone 12')->get();

        return view('test',['products'=>$allproducts],['bestsellerproducts'=>$bestsellerproducts],['newproducts'=>$newproducts]);
    }
    
}
```

My view Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>


<h2>Best Seller products</h2>
@foreach($bestsellerproducts as $bestsellerproduct)

<label>Name</label>
{{ $bestsellerproduct['name'] }}

<label>Price</label>
{{ $bestsellerproduct['price'] }}

@endforeach<br>


<h2>New products</h2>
@foreach($newproducts as $newproduct)

<label>BaseName</label>
{{ $newproduct['name'] }}

<label>Price</label>
{{ $newproduct['price'] }}

@endforeach<br>


<h2>All products</h2>
@foreach($products as $product)

<label>BaseName</label>
{{ $product['name'] }}

<label>Price</label>
{{ $product['price'] }}

@endforeach<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass all view variables in a single array, not multiple arrays:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $allproducts=product::all();
        $bestsellerproducts=product::where('category','iphone 11')->get();
        $newproducts=product::where('category','iphone 12')->get();
        return view('test',['products'=>$allproducts, 'bestsellerproducts'=>$bestsellerproducts,'newproducts'=>$newproducts]);
    }
       
}
```

Alternatively you can use `with`:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $allproducts=product::all();
        $bestsellerproducts=product::where('category','iphone 11')->get();
        $newproducts=product::where('category','iphone 12')->get();

        return view('test')
              ->with('products',$allproducts)
              ->with('bestsellerproducts', $bestsellerproducts)
              ->with('newproducts', $newproducts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much sir/ma This worked for me. I don't know if am typing this in the right section to reply you though hahaha....Thanks alot sir.

Comment: @ElijahIbe You're welcome. If this answers your question then you can also mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: How do i do that, am new here...where do I click on